# On Lévy collapsing the reals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Consider the [Lévy forcing notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_forcing_notions#Levy_collapsing). Let $M$ be a transitive standard model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Let $\aleph_n$ be the cardinality of the real numbers $2^\omega$ in $M$. Now collapse $\aleph_n$ to $\omega$. The resulting model $M[G]$ is again a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ but it is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $2^\omega$ is uncountable.

Could someone help me resolve this seeming contradiction? I'd be most grateful.

And I have a second question: Where can I access the original document containing the forcing notion explained? Or if that is not available: are there any other resources available? (I have a feeling that I might have been able to sort out my confusion on my own with more documentation available but Wiki and Jech are rather too concise for me.)

Comment: And a third question: Is it "Levy" or "Lévy"?

Comment: Transitive *and* standard? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't know. Whichever properties make it nice. They didn't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Transitive models are standard by definition... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila And is it "Levy" or "Lévy"?

Comment: I don't really know, I think the latter. For me it's לוי :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila : ) ${}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila And my other question in the post: where can I read about the Levy collapse? Jech's mention of it is minimal.

Comment: What do you want to read about it? I think that Kanamori has some nice theorems about the Levy collapse, it is in the chapter about forcing and the real numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I want to read about properties of the resulting model. Wouldn't that be in Lévy's original paper? Alas, I don't know the title of it.

Comment: By Kanamori, do you mean his book on the higher infinite?

Comment: I do; and what do you mean by "properties of the resulting model"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you also know the title of the original paper? As for the properties: I mean which theorems are true and which are false. For example, in Cohen's first model Krein-Milman is false. What if OMT is true in Levy's model? (Probably not, but maybe it is).

Comment: What is the Levy model? The collapse is in $\sf ZFC$, so the result is a model of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, that should have been "a Lévy model". A model in which there exists a bijection between the natural numbers and an $\aleph$ greater than $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, thanks. If I had access to the original paper...

Comment: You have access to Jech's book, as well Cohen's paper. You should know that forcing cannot change the truth value of the axiom of choice. For this we need to reduce to an inner model (usually a symmetric extension).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I want to read Levy's paper.

Comment: Too bad. I don't think it exists. The two prominent uses of the collapse are by Feferman-Levy and Solovay. There is no particular paper by Levy in which he describes the collapse. I can't find in Jech any reference to a particular paper by Levy which describes this forcing, and the historical notes of Chapter 15 point to the possibility it doesn't exist. You may be interested in [this paper](http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/11.pdf), and in particular page 11 of the .pdf file (and the references, of course).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for confirming its non-existence. And for the link.

Comment: Now that I dug up the Bell-Fremlin paper I realise that tb must've had all these thoughts already. Oh well.

Comment: Generally Jech's historical notes are very good, if it doesn't appear there then it's likely not to have existed. Kanamori's paper suggests that abstracts were announced, but that's about that. I can try and see if someone in Israel can get the original manuscripts... After all, reading a paper about forcing from 1963 is more or less equivalent to reading a paper in a language you can't understand. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you can get hold of Lévy's originals that would be more than super-awesome. With enough time I'll understand it and it'll be interesting to read. (As for my previous comment: on the bright side it means that I'm on the right track albeit several steps behind the asker of the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for every $\alpha<\aleph_{n+1}$ we add a bijection between $\omega$ and $\alpha$ to $M$. So in $M[G]$ all those ordinals are countable ordinals. So we added subsets of $\omega$ which encode these bijections (or the order type, if you prefer to think about that). So there are $\aleph_{n+1}$ new subsets to $\omega$ in $M[G]$.

Therefore we added $(\aleph_{n+1})^M$ real numbers to $M$, and changed $(\aleph_{n+1})^M$ to be $(\aleph_1)^{M[G]}$, because now whenever $\alpha<(\aleph_{n+1})^M$ we have that $M[G]\models|\alpha|=\aleph_0$. Therefore in $M[G]$ the least ordinal not in bijection with $\omega$ is $(\aleph_{n+1})^M$, which makes it $(\aleph_1)^{M[G]}$.

So we now have that $M[G]\models |2^\omega|=(\aleph_{n+1})^M=\aleph_1$.

---

As for reference request, I think that Kanamori's **The Higher Infinite** gives a nice exposition on the Levy collapse, as well one of its famous uses (constructing the Solovay model where all sets of reals are measurable).

Comment: (Ok, let me read your edit : )) Meh, you elaborated on the bit that I already understood :). Ok, let me think about why it follows from this that $M[G]\models 2^\omega = \aleph_1$...

Comment: @Matt: There. Another edit, which may help you to better understand me (which I know can be difficult most of the time...)

Comment: Ah, I finally get it. It's as "obvious" as I feared. Thank you very much!

Comment: Interesting. It seems to follow that in any $M[G]$ obtained by Levy collapsing $\mathsf{CH}$ holds even if $\mathsf{CH}$ was false in $M$.

Comment: A less explicit but shorter version of the answer: After you do this forcing, the set of reals *of your original model* is countable.  But the forcing has added new reals, so it's not guaranteed (and, as Asaf calculated, it's not true) that the set of reals *of your new model* is countable.  So your new model has no conflict with the theorem that the set of reals is uncountable.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It's clear to me now. Thank you.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you. If you happen to stay in Israel for a few days more, please let me know.